# How to use the same color for the same index of data in a column of Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[image]
I have the following Excel table, and now I need to draw a column chart.

The default column chart in Excel is as follows, how can I mark the same index with the same color?

For example, all bop correspond to one color, and all spp one color?

Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried selecting the bars and changing their colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest you cancel cell merge for "Trace".

You may select the cells of 410 group, cancel cell merge, then enter `=410` in formula bar, press **Ctrl + Enter** to fill 410 in selected cells. The same action for 420 group cells.

[image]

Then create a Pivot Table chart. The row field is "Trace", the column field is "Prefetcher", the values field is "SUM of test".

[image]